# How can i get full name using regex eg @test-user

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$send_message = preg_replace('/@(\w+).*?|<=+/u', "<a href='#'>@$1 </a>", 
$get_original_message);
```

But Problem is 
Example:

1. When i enter `@testuser` -> Its working fine
2. When i enter `@test_user` -> Its working fine
3. But When i enter `@test-user` -> its take only "test" but i need "test-user"
   Can anyone please help me on this
4. You can use online editor
   https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex, the \w sign does not accept the dash character.
And on the other hand, usually in usernames at the beginning and end of the word, the dash character is not allowed.
So we can change regex in such a way that it accepts Dash characters:

```
@(\w+-*\w*).*?|<=+
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for you replay i try different way and now its worked